# Can I use (cached) AMP for something more than (short of advance) SEO in a PWA solution?

Tags: amp-html, progressive-web-apps

Fast response **NO** (I fear)

As I start reading about AMP and PWA, I imagine I could use the AMP version served by google (probably faster than my server provider) to serve de APP-SHELL of my PWA solution, and once the user is already enjoining the content, load in background the rest of the PWA. But it seems is not.

Of course; I can serve the AMP from my server (that make me feel no so good) and short of emulate the previos described behaviour. But why I would like to tie myself up to the restrictive definition of AMP for that?.

Sure I can add the link to my PWA into the AMP pages served by google, so users can "install" my solution "without" have to "visit the web" (note al the quotes, I am writing from the user perspective), but that do not give really an advantage.

I would love that chrome uses this AMP version (served from google cache) to inject into the browser a locally cached version of the first requested HTML when loading a resource behind a search link. But that's not the case. (a lot of cross-site laws and philosophy got broken with this sentence, but anyhow, content is in the hands of google)

**Something wrong on my assumptions??**

Answer (score 0):

The [`amp-install-serviceworker` component](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-install-serviceworker) can be used to enable PWA features on your AMP pages. This is covered more in-depth in the article [Enable Progressive Web App features for your AMP pages](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/integration/pwa-amp/amp-as-pwa).

This means the pages remain valid AMP and thus would be cached and can be served from the AMP cache. You can then use the service worker to load other resources on your website in the background (which may include AMP pages or something else).

The only limitation is that the service worker can't operate on the cache itself. This means that accessing your pages that are cached will install, but won't activate the service worker. It will only run on your own domain.